# Is there anything special about the Sunnydale Hellmouth?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer

One of the premises of Buffy the Vampire Slayer is that extra amounts of weird things because Sunnydale sits on a [Hellmouth](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Hellmouth).

The show mentions that [Cleveland](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Cleveland) also has its own Hellmouth, and an issue of Spike mentions that there is yet another on Easter Island.

Buffy's presence in Sunnydale keeps the demons and other nasties in check - but is there anything particularly special about this Hellmouth? The other Hellmouths clearly do not need a Slayer-level protector to keep the world from ending (evidenced that during seasons 1-7, Buffy only travels to Cleveland [in the Wishverse](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Wishverse)). Why does Sunnydale attract the extra big/bad stuff?

I'm hoping/looking for an in-universe explanation and not something like "there wouldn't be a show otherwise".

Comment: It would have been interesting to see Buffy set in a different location, would have given the show a whole different feel

Comment: @APaleShadow If Eliza Dushku had wanted to do more Faith, it's possible that's what we would have seen...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well there's a few things that make Sunnydale a little more special than, perhaps, Cleveland's. For a start, The Master was trapped there. Secondly, Sunnydale was being run by a demon mayor. Thirdly, it was home to the Slayer Scythe. Lastly, in Season 8 (the comic) it's revealed that the Sunnydale Hellmouth also contains the source of all magic in our dimension.

So there's quite a few things going on in Sunnydale that make it unique!

It's also possible that The Powers That Be knew the Sunnydale Hellmouth was more dangerous than the Cleveland one (or any other ones around the world), and that's why Buffy found herself there. Since there's only ever one Slayer (except, you know, when there's more), she needs to be where she's needed most, I guess.

It's also possible that The Watchers, and possibly other groups, were taking care of the other Hellmouths around the globe.

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18755/why-is-the-world-not-completely-terrorized-by-demons-in-the-buffyverse) brought up the idea that other groups like the Scoobies or Angel Investigations may exist in other cities around the world. But as formidable as those groups may be, prior to season 8, none of them had a slayer.

Comment: @phantom42 No, but apparently Sunnydale had a military installation, so who's to say these other cities don't have one or two of their own?

Answer (score -1):

Here's my take on this. The Guardian who made the Slayer Scythe told how the first slayer used it to kill the last Old One. Perhaps this demon was creating a portal to hell to escape our world as the slayer engaged it, was defeated and killed but the demonic interdimensional energy lingered there, therefor the origin of Sunnydale's Hellmouth. Sunnydale is  the place where the first slayer killed the last old one. Eventually also over time the Turok Han were locked within the Seal of Danzalthar adding even more to the potent evil energy of the area.